# How do I give an SQL field an autovalue as a string (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, autonumber

I want insert multiple records into a table and I want the primary key to start as `ITS0001` and then increment by 1 for each record. For example:

```
Record 1 = ITS0001
Record 2 = ITS0002
Record 3 = ITS0003
Record 4 = ITS0004
Record 5 = ITS0005
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLServer IDENTITY Column with text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177584/sqlserver-identity-column-with-text)

Comment: I guess you expect to have no more than 10000 records?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible to make it in one column, but you can do it in two. The first one is a line number and the second one is a calculated column:

Observe the following example:

```
create table Table1 (
  number int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
  ajusted_number as 'ITS' + REPLICATE('0', 4 - 
        LEN(number)) + cast(number as varchar(4)) PERSISTED,
  Value int
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/feb8d/1/0)

Comment: OK, but I would also recommend to use the `PERSISTED` keyword on that computed column, to make it part of the actual table data (instead of re-calculating it on each and every single access)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my answer and totally agree with you.