# Create a complex Primary Key using Entity Framework code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I need to create a complex value via Entity Framework code-first, which includes three the following three values.

- A is a constant part look like "s#34"
- B is float and it's value come from a API webservice
- C is natural number!

I want to C generate automatically . In one example we have these Ids :

```
+-----+------+--+
|A    |B     |C |
+-----+------+--+
|s#34 |67889 |1 |
|s#34 |68988 |2 |
|s#34 |87665 |3 |
|s#34 |35458 |4 |
|s#34 |..... |5 |
...
```

I'm looking for a code like this:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[ID = "string1" + "string2" + default.ToString()]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

my mean from "default" in code come back to the value that get from (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).

Thank you for your help

Comment: Mind showing us what have you tried? Where are you having problem specifically? The `C` value you can generate either via `identity` or `sequence`, `A` you can hardcode in your code meanwhile `B` is just a normal variable you fetch from your webservice.

Comment: my question is about automatic generator! I don't want to check last entity ID in db to create a new row I want to use DataAnnotations abilities look like:"[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption)"

Comment: You could achive this using SQL Server custom identity column... refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177584/sqlserver-identity-column-with-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cramming all three pieces of information into one field would violate the single responsibility principle.  You should probably create a [composite key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873169/creating-composite-key-entity-framework), and then combine in a [computed column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585330/calculated-column-in-ef-code-first) if you need to concatenate the three columns for display.

Comment: I'm looking for a code like this:

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[ID = "string1" + "string2" + default.ToString()]
public int ID { get; set; }
my mean from "default" in code come back to the value that get from (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).