# how to generate custom ID in SQL server

Tags: mysql

i have this query to generate custom generated ID but I think this is incorrect please help me

```
SELECT CONCAT('STUDENT-',COUNT(Id), + 1) FROM `students`;
```

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `INT IDENTITY` column?

Comment: i have assigned the datatype of the ID Attribute to VARCHAR, just wanted to generate my own unique ID

Comment: You have tagged SQL Server, but the back ticks around student make me think it is MySQL - can you confirm?  Either way - don't use a varchar column for this - use a standard integer surrogate key - if you need to add `STUDENT-` to the start, just concatenate it with your ID **after** it has been auto generated. It is redundant to store `STUDENT-` every where that you need to refer back to this identifier.

Comment: MySQL Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix

Comment: SQL Server Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177584/sqlserver-identity-column-with-text

Comment: I think you made a mistake. Try the following `SELECT CONCAT('STUDENT-',COUNT(Id) + 1) FROM `students`;`

Comment: I am sorry https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048425/garethd for the tags yes it is for mysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8931450/leran2002 thanks but I would like to add date and time in between 'STUDENT-' and COUNT(ID) + 1

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this

```
SELECT 
    'STUDENT-' + CAST(COUNT(1) + 1 AS VARCHAR(20))
FROM 
    Students
```

Comment: not working You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CAST(COUNT(1)+1 AS VARCHAR(20))
       FROM Students
 LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

Select 'STUDENT-' + CAST(newid() as varchar(50)) from Students