# Is there a TSQL alphanumeric like IDENTITY column type?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there an IDENTITY like column type that generates alphanumeric values?
Like 023904F?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177584/sqlserver-identity-column-with-text

Comment: Are you asking for a IDENTITY column that counts in, for example, base 16 (0-F) or maybe base 36 (0-9,A-Z)? (For comparison: airline reservation systems use base-36 to identify reservations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES, the uniqueidentifier column, but it is 36 chars in length, try this:

```
select newid()
```

output

```
------------------------------------
53F2103C-C357-429E-A0E8-2DC26666638F

(1 row(s) affected)
```

you can use it like:

```
select LEFT(newid(),7)
```

and get:

```
-------
50D0F58

(1 row(s) affected)
```

this will not be unique though.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't get added to the table automatically, like an INT IDENTITY - you would have to define a DEFAULT CONSTRAINT on that column to specify `newid()` as default value - close, but not exactly the same, I'd say...

Comment: Will the `LEFT(newid(),7)` result in a unique value like `IDENTITY` does?

Comment: @marc_s, after reading the question again and your comment, I'm now not sure of what is being asked.  Does the OP want a semi-random char(7) or a sequential alphanumeric, an if so, what are the "rules", leading zeros, 0-9 and a-z or what? OP mentions identity, but is this to be unique?

Comment: @Raj More: good point - I doubt taking the first 7 chars off a GUID will be unique for too long a period of time!

Comment: @Raj More, no, in the answer I say this will not be unique though. you'd need all the original 36 chars to be unique.  Does the op want this to be unique?  they mention `identity` but little other details??

Answer (score 2):

No: you have to write a function to do it for you. Or concatenate "F" to a number in a computed columns

previous questions:

[SQLServer IDENTITY Column with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177584)

[Increasing Alphanumeric value in user defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987071)

Comment: +1, I now think the OP wants something like your second link `Increasing Alphanumeric value in user defined function`

Answer (score 0):

No - but you could always

- create an INT IDENTITY column
- add a computed column such as

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable 
     ADD ProductID AS CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)) + 'F'
  ```

  or whatever it is you want to do to the ID to make it into your alphanumeric field

Comment: this goes to what the OP wants, 6 numeric digits + 1 letter? or something else.  Looks like all three answers are for a different question, yet the OP didn't specify which of the three questions they are after.

Comment: @KM: yes, the question does leave quite a bit of room for interpretation.